# user-input condition MySQL query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to check the user input condition
but I got an error :Error: C:\Users\rakii\Desktop\clases\cmse406\New folder\covid-19-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Query. (C:\Users\rakii\Desktop\clase

I'm using MySQL database

```
app.post("/auth/sign-up/user", async (req, res) => {
    let { name, email, password } = req.body;
  
    let errors = [];
  
    console.log({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });
  
    if (!name || !email || !password ) {
      errors.push({ message: "Please enter all fields" });
    }
  
    if (password.length < 6) {
      errors.push({ message: "Password must be a least 6 characters long" });
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render("register", { errors, name, email, password});
    } else {
      hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      console.log(hashedPassword);
      // Validation passed
     db.query(
      `SELECT * FROM user WHERE userEmail VALUES ?`,
        [email],
        (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(results.rows);
  
          if (results.rows.length > 0) {
            errors.push({message: "Email already registered"});
            res.render("register",{errors});
          } else {
            db.query(
              `INSERT INTO users (userName, userEmail,userPassword)
                  VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
                  RETURNING id, password`,
              [name, email, hashedPassword],
              (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                  throw err;
                }
                console.log(results.rows);
                req.flash("success_msg", "You are now registered. Please log in");
                res.redirect("/users/login");
              }
            );
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why do you have `VALUES` there? It should be `WHERE userEmail = ?`

Comment: This is basic SQL syntax.

Comment: i change VALUES to = but i got another error C:\Users\rakii\Desktop\clases\cmse406\New folder\covid-19-app\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I don't think `results` has a `rows` property. It's just an array of results, not an object.

Comment: What does `console.log(results.rows)` show?

Comment: @Barmar 'console.log(results.rows)' showed this
  {
  name: 'Bob ',
  email: 'bob.mari@gmail.com',
  password: 'bob.mari@'
}

Comment: I doubt that. That looks like the output of `console.log({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });`

Comment: `results` is an array when the query is `SELECT`, it's an object when it's a DDL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a `SELECT` query, `results` is an array of all the rows, it's not an object with a `rows` property. So change

```
if (results.rows.length > 0)
```

to

```
if (results.length > 0)
```